# Highchart Z-Index practice not functioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

I have a highcharts scenario wherein my outer PIE and Inner PIE labels are getting overlapped for few cases.

Now, my requirement is that person

1. can click on PIE labels
2. can click on Outer Pie also.

Now the problem is that when someone click on overlapped area of OUTER PIE and one of the labels i.e. on area of 8% then click event of label is getting fired not of above Outer PIE.

I tried giving Z-index to series and labels but no help.

Comment: Recreate issue on jsFiddle, please.

Comment: @PawełFus .. it is very hard on JSFiddle as it is long long js...

Comment: Create jsFiddle as minified example.. Just chart options + dummy click events. So we can get reproduced demo and work on it/fix it.

Comment: @PawełFus .. Here is JS Fiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/gdkazb9q/  ...

Comment: Okay, so label **from inner** pie is overlapping **outer pie**. Thank you for the demo. In my opinion it works exactly I would expect. Label click is slicing pie part. I would rather move labels closer to connected slices, otherwise it is **very** confusing. Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/gdkazb9q/1/

Comment: Please check this demo ... http://jsfiddle.net/gdkazb9q/2/  .. and i am not allowed to move labels close to inner slice... any other way please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable events for `dataLabels` in CSS:

```
.highcharts-data-labels {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

And demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gdkazb9q/4/

Full solution for the above case by @Gags :

```
events:{
  mouseover: function() { 
    $(".highcharts-data-labels").css("pointer-events","none") 
  },
  mouseout: function() { 
    $(".highcharts-data-labels").css("pointer-events","visibleStroke") }
  }
}
```

Comment: but click on labels are also allowed... i can not permanently disable click on labels

Comment: i think we are very close to solution.. i applied above CSS on mouseover and it worked but how to remove pointer events none to again clickable in CSS on mouseout

Comment: Please, share with your solution, so other users can use that too :)

Comment: i used solution as `events:{mouseover: function() { $(".highcharts-data-labels").css("pointer-events","none") } }` and then `mouseout: function() { $(".highcharts-data-labels").css("pointer-events","visibleStroke") }`